# Existe algum problema em persistir uma imagem no postgres e ela seja do tipo bytea?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Tenho uma aplicação que estava usando o spring framework versão 4 (aplicação que gerava um .war cheia de configurações...) , ela funcionava  de forma plausível.

Porem,resolvi atualizar para a versão 5 (utilizando o spring boot, para deixar o projeto mais enxuto sem tantas classes de configuração...).

Assim considere:

Nessa aplicação tenho algumas entidades:

- um objeto do tipo avatar
- um objeto do tipo  usuário

Assim um usuário tem uma a relação do tipo @OneToOne com o avatar.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "avatares")
public class Avatar extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String titulo;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String tipo;

    @Lob
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private byte[] avatar;

    ...


@Entity
@Table(name = "usuarios")
public class Usuario extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    @Override
    public void setId(Long id) {
        super.setId(id);
    }

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String nome;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "avatar_id")    
    private Avatar avatar;
    ...
```

Quando usava a versão  4 do spring  ele persistia a entidade Avatar com o atributo avatar(array de bytes)  como sendo do tipo **oid** eu podia **buscar pelo usuário no banco e mostrar sua imagem de avatar sem problema algum.**

Veja na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quanto atualizei para o spring boot (**Spring Boot v2.1.1.RELEASE = Spring v5.1.3.RELEASE**) ele persiste com o tipo oid, e ate tudo bem , mas ao **buscar pelo usuário no banco e mostrar sua imagem de avatar dá a seguinte exception**:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Objetos Grandes não podem ser usados no modo de efetivação automática (auto-commit).
```

Esse problema não é de hoje já tem alguns meses que me deparei com ele, e vinha tentando de alguma forma sozinho resolver esse pequenino problema. Já tentei de tudo quanto foi tipo de configuração no arquivo de propriedades (application.properties) e nada, visitei fóruns.

> E por incrível que pareça com o mysql ele funciona perfeitamente sem
>   problema algum (Sim isso mesmo usando o spring 5)  usando a anotação @Lob!

Ai voce pensa : - por que voce não usa o mysql então?

Pelo simples motivo que eu estou usando a extenção postgis do postgres para um  proposito bem maior, e  me dediquei muito tempo , ate conseguir realizar as querys com  o tipo de dados Geometry.

Não sei se conseguiria fazer o mesmo com o mysql que suporta o tipo Geometry.

Qual a duvida afinal?

Para poder mostar o bendito avatar do usuário eu simplesmente removi a anotação `@Lob` do atributo avatar.Ai tudo perfeito ele salva no banco o array de bytes e depois eu recupero sem nenhuma exceção.

E dai?

Minhas imagens não podem passar de 100k segundo a regra de negócios de minha aplicação.(Não são imagens enormes..., são bem pequenas)

Com relação ao banco queria saber se isso tem algum impacto na performance da aplicação,  por que vi em algum lugar por ai que o tipo **oid**  é mais "leve" que o tipo **bytea**. Em outras palavras o tipo bytea vai tomar mais espaço na base de dados prechendo os espaços vazios com lixo de memoria... já o oid prenche apenas o espaço original da imagem.

Isso é verdade?

Em caso positivo, como eu poderia trazer de volta  o avatar usando a anotação @Lob que armazena o atributo como oid?